# Grafana greyed out Button Panel

Tags: grafana

I wonder if you can help me with that problem.
I downloaded the latest Grafana and plugin called Button Panel.

I am working on Linux for ARM.

CLI command below:

```
docker run -it -d -p 3000:3000 --network=grafana_network --name=grafana --restart=always -e "GF_INSTALL_PLUGINS=https://github.com/cloudspout/cloudspout-button-panel/releases/download/7.0.4/cloudspout-button-panel.zip;cloudspout-button-panel" grafana
```

and this is what i got after loggin in.

[image: sample grafana view]

What I should see is well shown here: https://grafana.com/grafana/plugins/cloudspout-button-panel.

Do you know what cause the problem or how to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Type in:

`docker run -it -d -p 3000:3000 --network=grafana_network --name=grafana --restart=always -e "GF_INSTALL_PLUGINS=cloudspout-button-panel " grafana`

no more greyed out.